# Why Google Cant able to Index all my webpages?

Tags: google, google-search-console, web-development, google-index

I created a website using Bootstrap and JS. and using JSON data for website content. But google cant able to index all of my web pages. What i have to include in my code so that Google Index my page. My website `https://www.faadoocoupons.com/ All links having ?fcId` (use for sorting data) cant able to get index in Google, like `https://www.faadoocoupons.com/Maharaja-Whiteline-15Liters-Classico-Geyser-White.html?fcId=2` I searched in Google, but haven't received any answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's indexed!

Check this https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:faadoocoupons.com/&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=41NXVrPaE-jI8AfUxb-gAg

Google that! You will find your site indexed.

Comment: check this link `https://www.faadoocoupons.com/Maharaja-Whiteline-15Liters-Classico-Geyser-White.html?fcId=2`

Comment: all links containing fcId are not indexed.

Comment: Check out this link for more detail https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/webmasters/-q1R7-7D9Ek;context-place=forum/webmasters